# Challenge when inserting records that has lookup field(that uses external Id of parent record)

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader, externalid, insert

In my scenario , I am loading records of object `xyz__c` in my system. This `xyz__c` has a lookup field that refers to `abc__c` object.

I am loading records using an external system. It maps the fields on `xyz__c` object accordingly , the lookup field to `abc__c` is mapped to a value( external id of `abc__c`). This value would connect the appropriate `abc__c` parent to `xyz__c` child.

**My problem :** I would like all of the records of `xyz__c` to be hooked to a single parent record of `abc__c`( example name[externalid name] - `Tree`). Whatever the value of `abc__c` record the external system maps when inserting I want to default it to - Tree before inserting `xyz__c` records.( This is because the external id of `abc__c` that the outside system send does not match with what is in my system)

**What I tried :** I wrote a before insert trigger to make change to the `abc__c` lookup field to have only the `value - Tree`.

**Challenge:** The records when inserting throws an error`(INVALID_FIELD:Foreign key external ID: 'smallTree' not found for field abc__c in entity xyz__c :)` even before it reaches the before insert trigger , this is preventing me to default the external id value for abc__c field to 'Tree'. I am not sure if there is a way I can access what external system send before it throws any error.

Any insights!

Comment: Generally speaking, no. External ID values are already resolved by the time your code gets a chance to run.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any salesforce documentation that I can use to support this argument?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm says "When the request comes from other sources, such as an Apex application or a SOAP API call, Salesforce validates only the foreign keys. Prior to executing a trigger, Salesforce verifies that any custom foreign keys do not refer to the object itself." Does that help?

Comment: Nice! Thanks for pointing that out. Just one question, what does - "Salesforce verifies that any custom foreign keys do not refer to the object itself." this means? specifically - "do not refer to object itself"- does it mean the foreign key on the record should not refer to the record itself? Please let me know an example if my understanding is incorrect.